# Catalog/product/list.phtml is using ul from somewhere

Tags: magento

I am editing catalog/product/list.phtml.

I am definitely in the right file/theme etc since adding a `<h1 Some Content /h1>` at the top of the page will produce Some Content on the correct part of the page inside the dotted red line of the template path hints.

Any changes made further down the file however, where not showing up.

On closer inspection I found that my list.phtml contained an `<ol>` tag  where as the information on the front end was contained within a `<ul>` tag.

I have no idea where magento is pulling this data from? Any ideas?

Comment: Very hard to understand what you are try to say.

Comment: Sorry about that, turns out I hadn't put enough spaces in front of my code. Anyway thanks for your time but I just anwered my own question, there is an unordered list at the bottom of the file, I was editing the ordered list at the top of the file which relates to a different view <Dunce: )